# How to group data into weekly and monthly SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

EDIT: Changed original question as I realised I made a mistake

If I have a list of products sold (fruits, grains, meat) for a certain period (e.g. 3 March to 25 March) how do I aggregate the data for each product on a weekly basis (every 7 days) starting from 3 March? In the event that the designated time period does not complete 7 days, e.g. 3 March to 25 has 2 days in the last week (3-9, 10-16, 17-23, ***24-25***), I need to extract an extra 5 days worth of data to fill in the week.

The same applies for Monthly (e.g. 1 June 2020 to 5 September 2020).

Comment: You want groups of seven days beginning with the start date end ending with the group containing the end date. For March 3 to to March 22 that would be March 3-9, March 10-16, and March 17-23. Is this correct? (In your request you have different groups that are even overlapping. This is a mistake, yes?)

Comment: You will get more help if you can post some sample data and the correspond expected result as formatted text (not image).

Comment: You are using "week" to mean a range of seven days. So we can start with the given start date and then count groups of seven days from there. A month, in contrast, is not a precice length of, say, 30 days. Some months are longer, some months are shorter. So, if you want to apply "monthly" as you apply "weekly", how long do you define a month's length?

Answer (score 0):

For a given range from March 3 to March 25, you want the periods March 3-9, March 10-16, March 17-23, and March 25-31. So the weeks start with the given start day, and the last week contains the given end day.

You only need some few calculations.

In order to get the real end date you need integer division:

```
real_end = start + ((end - start + 7) DIV 7) * 7 - 1
```

In order to know which group a date falls into, we use integer division again:

```
grp = (date - start) DIV 7
```

And, well, as the groups are numbered from 0 to n, we get the groups' start dates and end dates with:

```
grp_start = start + (grp * 7)
grp_end = start + (grp * 7) + 6
```

In SQL Server, integer division kicks in with the common division oparator (`/`) automatically, when the operands are integers. It is important hence to know whether the operands are guaranteed to be and remain integers. For the difference in days from start to end we use SQL Server's `DATEDIFF`. This function returns an integer, and we can assume that this will always be the case, for otherwise they would break existing code. We don't have to cast the result hence, but can rely on it staying an integer.

```
select
  fruit,
  dateadd(day, datediff(day, @start, sold_date) / 7, @start) as period_start,
  dateadd(day, datediff(day, @start, sold_date) / 7 + 6, @start) as period_end,
  sum(sold_amount) as total_sold
from fruit_sells
where sold_date >= @start
  and sold_date < dateadd(day, (datediff(day, @start, @end) / 7) * 7, @start)
group by fruit, datediff(day, @start, sold_date) / 7
order by fruit, datediff(day, @start, sold_date) / 7;
```

Comment: Thank you for this
However I am getting an error message at the end that says "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

Comment: Sorry, I had `@end` instead of `sold_date` in the group by clause. It is a good thing that SQL Server raises a syntax error here in spite of this not really being a syntactical, but rather a semantical problem. It makes no sense to group by a constant, and SQL Server tells us so. You could have spotted the error yourself, because in my explanation I have correctly `date - start`, while in my query I had `datediff(day, @start, @end)` instead of `datediff(day, @start, sold_date)`.